# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 46 on one ajax request on done of another

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I get TokenMismatchException when I make another ajax request from done of first one in jquery in laravel-5.0. I tried different Browsers but it yields to same output.

```
  var setting = {
                    url : 'http://localhost/enduewitapi/login',
                    type : 'GET',
                    dataType : 'json',
                    data : data,
                };
                setting.done = function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
                    var dataOne = {
                        dataOne : data
                    };
                    gen_ajax(sessionPath, 'POST', dataOne,
                        function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                            alert("Second ajax request successfull");
                        },
                        function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                            alert("second ajax request failed");
                            console.log(errorThrown);
                        },
                        function(jqXHR,textStatus){}
                    );
                },
                setting.fail = function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
                    alert(jqXHR.status);
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                },
                setting.always = function(jqXHR,textStatus){}
                Apiajax(setting);
```

Comment: What does data contain? The issue is related to https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf

Comment: My data looks like this :

Comment: var data = {
      emailOrmob : self.emailOrmob(),
      userPassword : self.userPassword(),
      rememberme : self.rememberme()
     };

Comment: I am using Laravel-5.0

Comment: You need to pass a valid CSRF token. Check this - https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/routing#csrf-protection

Comment: I included csrf in form , set x-csrf meta tag and also set x-csrf-token in ajaxSetup according to laravel-5/docs but it didnot work either way.If i comment out VerifyCsrfToken middleware in my 'main project' and 'api', than it works perfectly. But of course not verifying tokens is not a good idea.

Comment: You need to make sure that the ajax call takes that csrf token (either from meta tag or form) with the request and it will start working automatically.

Comment: I also sent token with data and that did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";
```

Then use the token inside ajax call as follows,

```
data: {
        '_token'          : token,
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

It is solved finally. I by mistake defined my api routes in web.php
rather than routes/api.php. Everything works perfect now.